# Find Javascript subclasses

Tags: javascript

How can I find all subclasses (both immediate, as well as all descendants) of a given Javascript "class"?  Note that Prototype (v1.6.0) supports this with "subclasses", but I am wondering about plain Javascript.

Comment: Javascript has no class, no style.. :(

Comment: You can get the **prototype** of an Object using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff877835(v=vs.94).aspx). Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Inheritance is a unidirectional relationship in JS. Unless you build something that handles your class generation and keeps track of subclasses, you can't do that (reliably).

Comment: you build your own way, just like Prototype does. there's many ways to do it...

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (at least ES5 and below) has no concept of classes, it only knows prototypes, which have no idea who used them as "super" or "sub" construction. The `Prototype` library only knows these relations when you exclusively use its own class model on top of plain JS, simply tracking it as part of its extension API.

Comment: FWIW, ES6 doesn't have "classes" either. The `class` syntax is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Sugar? But I'm syntacose intolerant D:

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Maybe you should stay away from it then :-/

Comment: For now, but with the ES6 `class` and `extends` syntax it is relatively easy for any ES6-implementing engines to also track the class relationships (at the very least because it makes JIT/shaping  even better)

Comment: **2017 update**: this is no longer "sugar" but simply a much better way to write out the logic for prototype based extensible classes.